# Argc not working for my C Prog, getting coredump

Tags: c, coredump, argc

I am writing a program to encrypt words. The thing is, the program works fine but when I put in 2/3 arg instead of 4, I'll get core dumped:
[image: I get Core Dumped when I'm having 3 arg.]

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <time.h>

int DisplayHelp(){ 
    printf("Usage :./task1 <wordlist> <min> <max>\n");
    printf("\t<wordlist> : A file path/name in which contains the password dictionary \n");
    printf("\t<min> : An integer value greater than 1.\n");
    printf("\t\tThis value represents the minimum length of the password\n");
    printf("\t<max> : An integer value greater than or equal to <min>.\n");
    printf("\t\t<max> represents the maximum length of the password.\n");
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[] ){ 
    char * type1="$1$";
    char * type6="$6$";
    char * salt="$";
    char * mdresult;
    char encyption_scheme[20];
    FILE * fp;
    FILE * fp1;
    char input1 [50];
    int length; 
    int line=0;
    int line2=0;
    int Min=atoi(argv[2]);
    int Max=atoi(argv[3]);

        if(Min>Max || argc!=4){
            DisplayHelp();
        }

            fp = fopen(argv[1],"r"); //Reading of file
        
            if(fp == NULL){
                printf("Fatal error! %s file not found\n",argv[1]);
                printf("Program halted. Please verify the file path and try again.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            fclose(fp);

            time_t current_time = time(NULL); 
            struct tm *tm = localtime(&current_time);

            printf("Program Started At %s\n", asctime(tm));

                fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
            while(fgets(input1,50,fp)){
                //line++; //Line +1
                length=strlen(input1)-1;
                input1[strlen(input1)-1]='\0';


                if(length >= Min && length <= Max){ 
                line++;
                strcpy(encyption_scheme,type1); 
                strcat(encyption_scheme,salt);
                mdresult = crypt(input1,encyption_scheme);
                line2++;

                strcpy(encyption_scheme,type6); 
                strcat(encyption_scheme,salt);
                sharesult = crypt(input1,encyption_scheme);
                line2++;

                fp1=fopen("Filename.txt","a");
                if (fp1==NULL)
                    exit(-1);
                fprintf(fp1, "%s:%s\n", input1, mdresult);
                fprintf(fp1, "%s:%s\n", input1, sharesult);
                fclose(fp1);
                }

            }

            printf("Total number of words processed     => %d\n", line);
            printf("Total number of generated entries   => %d\n", line2);

            fclose(fp);

            current_time = time(NULL);
            tm = localtime(&current_time);
            printf("\n");
            printf("Program Ended At %s\n", asctime(tm)); //Add time

        }
```

Comment: I make a dream that one day people will not learn programmation by starting with C. Hint: index start by 0 in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `argv[2]` and `argv[3]` before checking if they even existed. Change:

```
int Min=atoi(argv[2]);
int Max=atoi(argv[3]);

if(Min>Max || argc!=4){
    DisplayHelp();
}
```

to something like:

```
int Min, Max;

if (argc != 4) DisplayHelp();

Min = atoi(argv[2]);
Max = atoi(argv[3]);

if (Min > Max) DisplayHelp();
```

so you don't access elements of `argv` before you've verified they exist.

Comment: One would declare Min and Max only when needed.

Comment: @Stargateur: I was following the OP's existing style of declaring all (well, most) variables at the top of the block, rather than point of first use. C99 and later are fine with either, but I figured I'd avoid messing with their existing code organization further; some people just really like grouping their declarations. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Thanks man for the answer, really appreciate it :D
@ Stargateur: I'm sorry man. Im just a student. Dont be too hard on me just because I'm a beginner at this. Even I hope to improve. But I will take note of what you guys said!

Thanks again :D